# How to revert a pull request in Main branch?

Tags: azure

I pulled in my work into our main branch hosted on Azure on accident.  I want it to go back to before I pulled in my code.  How do I change this?

I've clicked on revert. but it's asking me to pick a branch? (my previous branch isn't there).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're previous branch is deleted on Pull request completion.

So optionally you can create a new branch from the main branch. You can treat this as your deleted branch. commands to run on your local machine :

1. Make sure you are in the Main branch : git checkout main
2. Create new branch from main : git checkout -b feature/mydeletedBranch
3. Push your new feature branch to remote : git push origin feature/mydeletedBranch

To set your Main branch to the previous pull request commit and omit the current one, commands to run locally :

1. Make sure you are in the Main branch : git checkout main
2. Run git log to identify the previous commit hash : git log -n 5
   [image]
3. Force remove the last commit from your main branch. Here I'm going back to a previous commit. In my example I want to go back to 38fa66d4abf8dbf02c07bcc816bba280e7d8dcf0 : git reset --hard 38fa66d4abf8dbf02c07bcc816bba280e7d8dcf0
   [image]
4. Now run git log again to verify your history. You can see the last commit is no longer in history
   [image]
5. Force push your updated local Main branch to remote : git push origin main --force

This will reflect the changes in your remote branch. And you wont have that particular PR commit in history.

PS : assumed that the merged pull request commit you want to remove is the last commit done in the main branch.